# How do I open a Facebook link in the Facebook app?

Tags: android

Consider:

```
dataTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent facebookIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/1149231332XXXX/"));
        startActivity(facebookIntent);
    }
});
```

But it always open this URL in the browser instead of the app.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://graph.facebook.com/ (https://graph.facebook.com/fsintents for instance).

```
public static Intent openInFBApp(Context context) {
    try {
        context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
        return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://page/<id_here>"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/<user_name_here>"));
    }
}
```

Comment: How to get "id"?

Comment: @MehulSantoki check this link - https://support.wix.com/en/article/accessing-your-facebook-business-page-id. Please vote :-)